# fontconfig.conf file with texlive on Microsoft Windows

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontspec

I have the texlive 2019 distribution installed on Microsoft Windows 8.1.
I have some Opentype fonts that I would like to use in my LaTeX documents with xelatex and lualatex.
I have followed the recipe given in Section 3.4.4
"System font configuration for XeTEX and LuaTEX":

1. Copy the texlive-fontconfig.conf file to ~/.fonts.conf, where ~
   is your home directory.
2. Run fc-cache -fv.

I have created this .fonts.conf file from the file 
TEXMFSYSVAR/fonts/conf/texlive-fontconfig.conf

where I added my directory at the end of the three entries present these, as such :

```
<dir>C:/windows/fonts</dir>  
<dir>C:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype</dir>  
<dir>C:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype</dir>  
<dir>c:/Users/goossens.tbappres/goossenswork/texwork/texmf/fonts/opentype</dir>
```

However running fc-cache -fv does not include my files in the fonts database, so that xelatex and lualatex cannot find them.

Some relevant environment variables are:

```
HOMEPATH=\Users\goossens.tbappres
TEXMFHOME=C:\Users\goossens.tbappres\goossenswork\texwork
```

Where should I put my fonts.conf file so that my files are included in the fonts database?

Comment: Hi Michel, I don't use the windows setup but the places fontconfig looks is a bit variable ~/.fonts.conf is possibility but they are deprecating that .fonts form as far as I can see, fontconfig manual says ... please note that ~/.fonts.conf.d is deprecated now. it will not be read by default in the future version.   easiest of course is simply to drop the fonts into windows/fonts

Comment: Imho the instructions your are citing are for linux. I never tried to extend the fontconfig configuration of texlive in windows -- a local.conf file in the right place should probably work for xelatex -- but in view of your path it is in my opinion much more sensible to simply add your texmf as a new root with `tlmgr conf auxtrees add c:/Users/goossens.tbappres/goossenswork/texwork/texmf`.

Answer (score 1):

First, run a command:

```
kpsewhich --var-value=FONTCONFIG_PATH
```

Go to a directory shown by the above command.
In the directory, create a file local.conf with the following
contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<!-- local.conf file to configure local font access -->
<fontconfig>

<!-- 
  Find fonts in these directories and their subdirectories
  Example:

<dir>c:/somedir/fonts/opentype</dir>

-->

<dir>c:/Users/goossens.tbappres/goossenswork/texwork/texmf/fonts/opentype</dir>

</fontconfig>
```

Comment: Thanks to Akira Kakuto. His suggestion makes my files indeed findable. But it needs me to introduce a file into the texmf distribution tree. I would have preferred a solution where I could put the file in my personal user space, as suggested in Section 3.4.4 of the texlive manual.

Comment: @Goossens Michel: Sorry for the inconvenience. Note that local.conf
is not overwritten by updates of TeX Live. If you don't like the
above solution, I think you can define an environment variable like
`FONTCONFIG_PATH_EXTRA=c:/your/favorite/dir`
and move the file local.conf to the directory `c:/your/favorite/dir`.
Note that only one local.conf is read.
BTW, `fontconfig` is not used in the case of `luatex`.
Please follow comments by Ulrike for `luatex`.

Comment: @Goossens Michel: `fontconfig` for TeX Live Windows is slightly
modified and it is quite possible that it differs from
usual manual, sorry.